# Screen (not Lock Screen) Timeout Stuck at 1 Minute

Tags: windows, windows-registry, screensaver, timeout, lock

I recently got a new laptop (Lenovo T440p with Windows 8.1 Pro) and was having the following issue: the screen would lock (screen would go black and require a password to get back in) after **1 minute**. I would prefer something more like 10 or 15 minutes. So, I tried the obvious changes (check the screensaver settings, power management settings for sleep, turning off the screen, etc.), with no success. I did, however, notice a rather odd behavior: if I changed the screensaver timeout from 1 minute to anything else (say, 15 mins), clicked OK, and re-opened the screensaver settings window, it would be back to 1 minute. Odd.

At that point, I turned to Google. I found posts ([this one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ace4085a-b0ba-4a98-898d-cd92d9e88e13/windows-8-cannot-change-screensaver-timeout?forum=w8itprogeneral#4ec0f754-c592-40e4-8518-7022c52c4a72) in particular was helpful) suggesting all sorts of causes and resolutions:

- If you have Cisco AnyConnect VPN client (which I did), try uninstalling it. I uninstalled, rebooted, no change.
- Open the User Accounts control panel and, on the left side of the screen, click Reset Security Policies. My User Accounts control panel, however, has no such link.
- Reboot into a repair console and run "sfc /scannow". It did indeed find and repair some issues, but didn't fix the screen timeout problem.
- Edit the Group Policy to force a particular timeout time; the setting showed up correctly (15 mins) in screensaver settings, power management settings, etc., but the screen would still go black and lock after 1 minute.
- In the registry, manually change the screensaver timeout and the "turn off the screen" timeout. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I had to dig through the output from [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what other settings might be getting set (by who-knows-what) when I changed my screensaver settings. I found a registry key I haven't seen before:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\InactivityTimeoutSecs
```

It was set to 60 (seconds). I updated it to 900 (15 minutes), and it worked!

I still don't know how that got set in the first place, or why my screensaver timeout kept reverting to 1 minute (it doesn't anymore, since I changed that registry key), but if you have any ideas to help explain it, I'm all ears (or eyes, I suppose). Still, since this caused me so much time and frustration, I wanted to post what finally worked in case it can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

i had this issue also, it turned out it was getting the mobile device settings from exchange and locking like a phone would. tested it out by editing the exchange setting and that was it. turns out i must have miss-clicked on windows mail and setup my email account and it started pulling these settings.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

> Start/Search and type gpedit.msc, Right click the gpedit results and
>   Run As Administrator. In the Elevated Group Policy Editor, on the Left
>   Panel, go to User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Control
>   Panel/Personalization/Enable Screen Saver and enable the Policy.
>   Once you have enabled that policy, go down and also enable Screen
>   Saver Timeout.  Note that in the Screen Saver Timeout policy there's
>   an option to set the number of second for the timeout with the default
>   being 900 seconds or 15 minutes.
>
> Once you've enabled both policies and set the timeout if different
>   from the default, exit the group policy editor.  If you now go the
>   screen saver settings in Control Panel you will notice that the wait
>   period will match the minutes you entered in the group policy editor
>   but it will be grayed out preventing you from changing the value
>   unless you go back into the group policy editor and change it there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with Windows 10. In the end I found a solution which is easier than going into regedit.
From the Windows Start button go into 'Settings' and type "Screen saver" in the 'Find a setting' box at top right of the screen. On the new screen click 'Change screen saver'. Then minimise the page, and you should find a 'Screen saver settings' page hidden underneath it. In my case this was set to 1 minute, and resetting it to 15 minutes solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Just Go through Link this help me:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/Machine-always-goes-into-standby-mode-after-1-min-of-being-idle/ta-p/414093

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful.  Please edit your answer, and include all relevant information, be sure to quote and cite any sources you might use for that information.