# win 10 lock screen timeout stuck at 1 minute

Tags: windows, lock-screen

I use win 10 version 21H1 (Build 19043.1083). I had my lock screen timeout at 5 minutes, working fine. Then I took an online proctored exam by PearsonVue and needed to install OnVue software, which messed up all sorts of settings. Most annoyingly, the screen timeout setting. Its now at 1 minute, which is a time I often spend without any action when reading something.

So I tried several things to fix this:

1. I followed this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/267893/how-to-change-the-windows-10-lock-screen-timeout/ where I set the following:
   [image]

No success unfortunatly

2. I found a post on superuser ([Screen (not Lock Screen) Timeout Stuck at 1 Minute](https://superuser.com/questions/868126/screen-not-lock-screen-timeout-stuck-at-1-minute)), suggesting the following registry setting, which also seems fine:

[image]

Also no success.

So I am wondering what is left that I can do to fix the screen lock timeout which is still at 1 minute, even after several reboots. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally, with the help of a wonderful colleague, I was able to fix this: In the settings menue for the lock-screen, settings for screensaver, there was configured that no screensaver schould be used, however with a timeout of 1 minute. That could not be changed without enabling a screensaver. I did so, then changed the value to 10 minutes, and disabled the screensaver again. Now the 1 minute timeout is gone.

How wired. For your reference, here is a screenshot - sorry its in germen - hope it is useful to someone:

[image]